# node.js: Key-Value pair added to Object but not shown when Object is printed

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have a javascript Object `obj` with the fields:

```
{ key1: val1,
  key2: val2,
  key3: 
       [{subkey1: subval1,
         subkey2: subval2 },
        {subkey3: subval3,
         subkey4: subval4 }],
  key4: val4
}
```

Now if I add a key value pair to this object,

```
obj.key5 = val5;
```

and print the `obj` Object (by `console.log(obj)` ), it doesn't show the `key5: val5` pair.

However, doing `console.log(obj.key5)` does output `val5`, so the key value pair is being added.

Why doesn't it show on print the whole object?

I even tried creating a duplicate object and assigning `key5` to the new one, but it behaves similar to the original object.

I tried using `Object.assign()` to give the same results as above.

I need to pass the `obj` Object as an argument to another API, and even though `obj.key5` exists, on passing it as an argument, the API doesn't read `key5'.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `obj` being returned from `mongo` ?

Comment: It's a standard Javascript Object, a mongoose model, ... ?

Comment: `obj` is a standard Javascript Object.

Comment: Can you post your complete code, with all the vals?

Comment: Update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34352323/3549458

Comment: (I don't know whether the object is mutable OR not !!!)   try obj["key5"] = val5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On printing the object (i.e. `console.log(obj)` ), it doesn't show me the `{key5:val5}` pair.

But if I do `console.log(obj.key5)`, it does show me `val5`.

Maybe it is something to do with asynchronous execution of statements in node.js, where `console.log(obj)` is executed before the `obj.key5 = val5` assignment?